# Is there any WMS/WFS to get soil data of US?

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs, soil

I am developing a QGIS script that requires Soil Data as Input. Without automation one can go to this link, upload Area of Interest Boundary, and download the data.

https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/WebSoilSurvey.aspx

I have found these links as well and have tried to add these connections, but none of them is working.

https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx

https://data.nal.usda.gov/dataset/soil-data-access-web-service/resource/b806fe02-041c-4902-9441-e3a042cb0227

[image]

What I want to do finally is to create an script/model that will clip the soil data for my area of Interest so that I can perform spatial analysis on it. The soil data should have Hydrologic Soil Group or Map Unit Symbol as one of the attribute.

Comment: try STATSGO2 https://nrcsgeoservices.sc.egov.usda.gov/arcgis/rest/services/GlobalSoilMap_v01_STATSGO2/pHx10/MapServer

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo it is about QGIS as well because I have found few WMS and WFS URLs for my data that are not working.

Comment: There does seem to be something wrong with the https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx services.  Best bet would be to contact the service contact and tell them about the issues see the GetCapabilites response for details ~ https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMWGS84Geographic.wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: @Mapperz doesn't look like they have HSG data that I need.

Comment: @nmtoken I have contacted them. Let's see what they say.

Comment: @ nmtoken I contacted the sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov and according to them, the request is bad because:
it is switching X&Y parameters, SRS should have been defined for both the bounding box and for the output, and coordinate pairs are separated by a space instead of another comma

Apparently QGIS is sending a bad request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research and communication with GIS team of USDA, and QGIS team. I have found out that the WFS to get soil data of US are:

https://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMWGS84Geographic.wfs
https://SDMDataAccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs

But, they are misconfigured and QGIS can't communicate with them. Let's hope that this problem is fixed in the near future.

Meanwhile there is a QGIS Plugin called 'Curve Number Generator' that can download Soil as a shapefile for any AOI within the contiguous US